# Search all pdf file from Device android 30 and above using mediaQuery?

Tags: android

below android 28 i can easily search all pdf files using

```
                    walkdir(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())
```

Now in android 29 and above i dont get any pdf list i know google changed its policies using storage i had tried SAF but i think it is only working in android 29 but above it not working so i moved to **MediaQuery** but the thing is if i search image, video it is working fine using Permission     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_MEDIA_IMAGES" />`
but not working for pdf or files anybody have any idea can it be possible now or cant access files outsinde app sandbox my code for accessing files is below i download an pdf in download Folder and images too images are getting correctly except pdf files

```
private fun getPdfList(): ArrayList<String>? {
    val pdfList = ArrayList<String>()
    val projection = arrayOf(
        MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
        MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA,
        MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE,
    )
    val sortOrder = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATE_ADDED + " DESC"

    val selection = "${MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE} = ?"
    val mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("pdf")
    Log.e("TAG", "MIME Type: $mimeType")
    val selectionArgs = arrayOf(mimeType)

    val collection: Uri = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
        MediaStore.Files.getContentUri(MediaStore.VOLUME_EXTERNAL_PRIMARY)
    } else {
        MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external")
    }

    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
            this,
            android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
        ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
    ) {
        Log.e("TAG", "PERMISSION ALREADY GRANTED")

        contentResolver.query(collection, projection, selection, selectionArgs, null)
            ?.use { cursor ->
                Log.e("TAG", "${cursor.count}")

                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    val columnData = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DATA)
                    val columnName =
                        cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME)
                    Log.e("columnName", "$columnName")

                    do {
                        val filePath = cursor.getString(columnData)
                        val fileName = cursor.getString(columnName)
                        pdfList.add(filePath)
                        Log.e("TAG", "PDF File Name: $fileName, Path: $filePath")
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext())
                }
            }
    } else {
        Log.e("TAG", "Permission not granted")
    }

    return pdfList
}
```

Comment: It should at least list the pdfs your app created itself. Now does it?

Comment: yes if i created a pdf and save it then it can be accessed i think what google advice cant access files outside app sandbox so do you have any solution